# NextJS not Automatically Reloading After Saving

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm currently trying to build a web app with NextJS. I have used npx create-next-app. But for some reason it doesn't reload when I save changes. I get the reload symbol but the content doesn't update. I would appreciate your help.

Thank you in advance!

```
 "scripts": {
"dev": "next dev",
"build": "next build",
"start": "next start",
"lint": "next lint"
```

},
"dependencies": {
"next": "11.0.0",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-dom": "17.0.2"
}

Comment: are you using `next dev` during development? what did you do that didn't reload after saving?

Comment: That may happen sometime due to webpack 5 caching strategy which is still experimental.